# VirtualStringTree lock column 0

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Is it possible to lock column 0 (with node names)  in [`VirtualStringTree`](http://www.jam-software.com/virtual-treeview/index.shtml) during horizontal  scrolling like in Excel?

Answer (score 6):

If I recall correctly this feature was introduced in version 5. To make a column fixed set `coFixed` in it's `Options` (select the tree component, then `Header` -> `Columns` then you can access to the properties of the columns).